# Implementing the $\theta$-method for solving an IVP

Tags: algorithms, matlab

I also posted this question on the [Math SE site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327062/implementing-the-theta-method-for-solving-an-ivp), but it was suggested I post here also.

I want to implement the $\theta$-method to solve an IVP in MATLAB. The $\theta$-method is:

$y_{j+1} = y_j + h[\theta f(t_j, y_j) + (1 - \theta)f(t_{j+1}, y_{j+1})]$ for $\theta \in [0, 1]$.

I want to use it to solve an IVP of this form:

$y_1\prime = f_1(y_1, y_2) \;\;\;\;\; y_2\prime = f_2(y_1, y_2)$

$t \in [a, b]$

$y_1(a) = \alpha \;\;\;\;\; y_2(a) = \alpha \;\;\;\;\;\;$ (The initial conditions)

I'm not sure how I would implement this, since I'm used to implementing methods in which there is only one DE, such as $y\prime=f(t, y)$ (like Euler's method or the Runge-Kutta).

Here is what I did so far in MATLAB:

```
function thetaMeth(a, b, h, f, y)

    j = 1;
    theta = 0.5
    for i = a:h:b
        y(j+1) = y(j) + h*(theta*f(j, y(j)) + (1 - theta)*f(j+1, y(j+1)));
        fprintf('t = %f; y(%d) = %f\n', i, j, y(j));
    end
        j = j + 1;
end
```

My parameter `f` would be for the $y_1\prime$ and $y_2\prime$ equations (it could possibly be taken in as a cell array of functions). I'm not sure what to do with the `y` parameter, because the solution equations $y_1$ and $y_2$ are not given (I'm not really sure if I should even have `y` as a parameter). This is an implicit method, and you need to have $y_{j+1}$ calculated beforehand somehow, because it appears in the LHS and RHS.

Anyone have any pointers as to how I can implement this? It doesn't have to be in MATLAB, I just need an algorithm that can be translated into code, since I'm not sure how to implement the algorithm myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the formula that you use for the $\theta$-method is correct, but beware that you mix the indices for the time advancing with the indices of the components. Write for example $y^{(i)}_j$ for the component $j$ of the solution at time $t_i$. This can avoid confusions.

If the system of ODEs that you want to solve is

$$ \mathbf{y}\prime = f(t,\mathbf{y}) $$

i.e. written in components

$$ \left\{\begin{array}{c} y_1\prime = f_1(t,\mathbf{y}) \\ y_2\prime = f_2(t,\mathbf{y}) \end{array} \right.$$

with $\mathbf{y}= \left( \begin{array}{c} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{array} \right)$ and $f(t,y) = \left( \begin{array}{c} f_1(t,\mathbf{y}) \\ f_2(t,\mathbf{y}) \end{array} \right)$. As you mention, the scheme is $$\mathbf{y}^{(j+1)} = \mathbf{y}^{(j)} + h \left( \theta f(t_j, \mathbf{y}^{(j)}) + (1-\theta)f(t_{j+1}, \mathbf{y}^{(j+1)})\right)$$

which is implicit. The fact that it is implicit scheme implies that (in general) you cannot find directly $\mathbf{y}^{(j+1)}$ from $\mathbf{y}^{(j)}$, but you need to solve non-linear equations. Indeed, you can rewrite the scheme as
$$G(\mathbf{y}^{(j+1)}) =\mathbf{y}^{(j+1)} - \mathbf{y}^{(j)} - h \left( \theta f(t_j, \mathbf{y}^{(j)}) + (1-\theta)f(t_{j+1}, \mathbf{y}^{(j+1)})\right) = \mathbf{0}$$.

So, at each time step of your algorithm, you need to solve this non-linear equation. This can be done for example with the Matlab function `fzero` (applied to each component of the equation). That is what you should do in your `for` loop.

For the implementation, you can use an anonymous function for `f`, it supports vectorial valued functions. Instead of `y`, take `alpha` as argument. Then, `y` is the output of your function (possible with the times to which the approximations correspond).

Hope it helps!